# Getting data from excel file when any cell is in edit mode

Tags: excel, vb.net

I get data from excel file to vb.net application. Cell with data and worksheet is protected. User need to make same changes in different worksheets and the problem is when user forget to accept changes. The cells are in edit mode. My code couldn't get any data then.

```
            Try
                rng = CType(oexcelsheet.Cells(7, 5), Excel.Range)
                Label2.Text = rng.Value

            Catch exts As Exception

            End Try
```

How to get data form the cell when other cells are in edit mode?

Comment: did you manage to fix you issue ?

Comment: Unfortunatelly no. As far as I readed there is no simple solution for this.